# How to use java ee 6 @Resource annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

The java ee 6 api has an annotation [@Resource](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) with an attribute 'lookup', however, so does the java se 6 api ([here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)). However, since java ee 6 is dependent on java se 6, it seems you can not get at the ee version of the annotation and the 'lookup' attribute.

Is this a bug or is there some other way to use this annotation that I am missing.

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JDK (and mine) doesn't have  the latest version of the `javax.annotation.Resource` from the [JSR-250](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250). To use the latest version during compilation, you'll have to override the compiler's endorsed directory (e.g. to point to your glassfishv3 endorsed directory):

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${GLASSFISH_HOME}/modules/endorsed
```

Comment: I'll give this a try later today - if it works I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: This works, thanks. Just a note to anyone else out there who may hit this issue and is using Maven:
You can use the argument above combined with your mvn compile & package runs.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same class in both cases (`javax.annotation.Resource`). It's in both sets of API docs for convenience only. Actual JavaEE 6 implementations will just use the class from JavaSE 6.

Comment: I beg to differ. The lookup element (http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html#lookup()) is not present in the se version.

Comment: Hmm, so it does. OK, that's officially weird. I hope this isn't the JCP screwing up. Again.

Comment: I've seen examples of the Resource lookup element used, I just can't figure out how - in every scenario I've played with it seems the compiler defaults to the se annotation class and not the ee version.

Comment: @javamonkey79: That makes sense, the VM won't let its own classes be overridden without some special moves - as far as the VM in concerned, they *are* the same. It looks increasingly like a mistake in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Thread necro at its best, but for my taste - trying to do things clean and neat - the approach of javamonkey79 is just too much of a hack.

This is what I put in my pom.xml to make it work:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>endorsed</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- javaee6 contains upgrades of APIs contained within the JDK itself.
                                 As such these need to be placed on the bootclasspath, rather than classpath of the
                                 compiler.
                                 If you don't make use of these new updated API, you can delete the profile.
                                 On non-SUN jdk, you will need to create a similar profile for your jdk, with the similar property as sun.boot.class.path in Sun's JDK.-->
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar${path.separator}${sun.boot.class.path}</bootclasspath>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

By the way, I found this [here](http://java-abwaschbar.blogspot.com/2011/01/resource-annotation-and-lookup.html). Thanks a lot, Frederik!

Comment: To be exact, it is not my solution, but Pascal Thivent's. However, I like your maven driven solution as well - sometimes thread necro is ok if it helps someone else out, or at least documents something for yourself. +1 for you sir (or mam)!