# The attribute lookup is undefined for the annotation type Resource

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jms

Giving JMS a first shot, when I try to inject `@Resource(lookup="jms/ConnectionFactory")`, I get the error:

> The attribute lookup is undefined for the annotation type Resource

I just read [How to use java ee 6 @Resource annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495271/how-to-use-java-ee-6-resource-annotation), but I haven't study Maven yet, so I was wondering, if I can fix this issue some other way rather than using Maven?

I'm using Eclipse by the way.

Comment: You're probably using a different Resource annotation. Check that your impòrts contain `import javax.annotation.Resource;`

Comment: I've already imported that package

Comment: Then you're using an old version of this annotation (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html: the annotation doesn't have a lookup attribute in Java EE 5). You have an old jar in the build path.

Comment: No sir, I'm using GlassFish v3.1, which is assumed to have Java EE 6

Comment: If you had the right jar in your build path, you wouldn't get this compile error. Ctrl-click the annotation class and check which jar it comes from.

Comment: the class turned out to be coming from The SE library, Now how can i have Eclipse ignore it, and make it understand that i want the EE one ? when I tried to remove the JRE from the classpath, the error is gone

Answer (score 5):

The right fix for this is to right-click your project in Eclipse, Java Build Path -> Order and Exports, select JRE System Library and click on Bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the mappedName attribute as:

```
@Resource(mappedName="jms/ConnectionFactory")
```

Also if you still want to use lookup, then take a look at the javax.annotation.jar you are using. Lookup  attribute was introduced in JavaEE 6. Probably you have an older version.

Answer (score 1):

One common issue that Java EE 6 developers meet is the use of the @Resource annotation which conflicts with the JDK built-in  @javax.annotation.Resource. Here we will show how to solve the compilation issue in Eclipse and Maven.

If you have a look at the @Resource annotation included in Java EE 6, it includes  the lookup attribute. Unfortunately, as we said, the  JDK itself ships its own version of @javax.annotation.Resource which doesn't have this attribute. This leads to a compilation problem either if you are using Eclipse or Maven.

```
public class MyCache {
    @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/cluster")
    private CacheContainer container;
}
```

[ERROR] symbol  : method lookup()
[ERROR] location: @interface javax.annotation.Resource
Solving the issue in the Eclipse environment is quite easy: all you need to do is adding the JBoss EE 6 implementation of the @Resource annotation - AND - put it ahead of the JDK libraries

@resource maven lookup
The JBoss library is should be named jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar (or something like that) in the AS 7 release and jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar in the EAP 6

If you are compiling with Maven, then the simplest way to solve this issue is to add the annotation JAR library into the endorsed dir of your JDK, so that it will override the default @Resource implementation.

The annotation JAR needs to be copied into the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/endorsed of your JDK distribution.

As an alternative you can pass the  -Djava.endorsed.dirs to the JVM parameters, as shown by the following Maven build from Eclipse